# Strange behavior of NSPredicate,

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nspredicate

Why does this predicate returns results:

```
predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemsString like '*{4160366}*'"];
```

while this predicate returns empty array

```
predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemsString like '*{%@}*'",[NSString stringWithString:@"4160366"]];
```

I's driving me crazy

Comment: Can you try using NSNumber instead of NSString?

Comment: Not sure if this makes a difference, but try: `predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemsString like '*{%@}*'",@"4160366"];`

Comment: @mohabitar: this will do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building a predicate, predicateWithFormat automatically adds quotes when performing variable substitution.  So your (second) predicate ends up looking like this:

`itemsString like '*{"4160366"}*'"`.

Notice the extra set of quotes.

Change it to:

```
predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemsString like %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"*{%@}*", @"4160366"]];
```

and it should work.

(Note that instead of using `stringWithString` I just used `@""` which does the same thing.)

Comment: Thank you very much !! I didn't expected that predicateWithFormat automatically adds quotes.